# Issue in find_each method in Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here's the erroneous code snippet.

```
transaction do    
    Person.having_email(some_email).find_each(:conditions => ["people.identifier != ? OR people.identifier IS NULL", identifier]) do |person|
        if person.identifier?
          raise "Person is associated with a different identifier"
        else
          duplicate_entry =  Person.find_by_identifier_and_company_id(identifier, person.company_id)
          person.update_attribute(:identifier, identifier) if duplicate_entry.nil?
        end
    end
end
```

`having_email` is a named_scope defined for the Person class.

The issue that I'm facing is that the expression that finds a possible duplicate entry always seems to be returning nil even when a valid record is present in the db. When I evaluate the same expression using the RubyMine debugger, it returns the correct object.

On further introspection, it seems that rails is not firing any query on the duplicate_entry evaluation statement(there is no such query in the logs). On replacing the `find_each` call with a normal `find(:all, ...).each` call, things seem to work fine(The duplicate entry retrieval query is present in the logs as well).

I haven't been able to get my head around what might be causing this. Any ideas?

Comment: @vise It's not exactly an "error" per se, more of an issue which is that the correct person object is not being fetched from the db using the dynamic finder inside the find_each block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that find_each and find_in_batches work by setting up a
>   with_scope block. Therefore, if you need to do any other finds on that
>   same model, the scope will apply.

The root cause of this issue has been explained quite well along with a valid workaround [in this blog post](http://davedupre.com/2009/05/20/gotcha-with-find_each-and-find_in_batches/)

Comment: link is now broken and because you didn't include the solution in your answer no one visiting this can know how to solve it..

Comment: Ahh, sorry for that mate. It a very old post, don't really remember the solution either. :(

Comment: Here is the updated link I guess : http://www.davedupre.com/blog/2009/05/20/gotcha-with-find_each-and-find_in_batches